# How do LSM Tree based DBs deal with concurency when updating the MemTable

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, key-value-store

Reading about LSM Trees in several blogs I have wondered how do actual implementations deal with concurrency in when receiving several simultaneous requests to insert values which would modify the in memory structure of the MemTable.

- When inserting a value to the MemTable (which most seem to indicate is a tree)

  - How does it deal with multiple insertion requests at the same time?
  - How does it deal with read/write races?
  - Does it use a simple R/W lock mechanism ?

Comment: Would appreciate a comment of feedback ?

Comment: Please only ask one question per question.  Questions with a multitude of questions usually get closed.

Comment: @Aaron I was hoping to basically target the issue of synchronization in such DBs in general but I see your point, hopefully the edited version is better

Comment: As Erick mentioned in Cassandra last write wins. So whichever data is written last is the actual data. If you want to avoid a race condition like two threads reading at the same time and updating values according to them, then you should handle it at application side. For example you can do this : before querying C*, application can take lock based on partition key. So the thread which has the lock executes its query without worrying about values changing in database. This is one of the example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cassandra, mutations with the latest timestamp wins so it can handle thousands of concurrent insertions and there is no race to deal with and there are no locks required.

The SSTables are immutable -- they never change once written to disk. But the data can be rewritten by compaction threads which merges SSTables into new SSTables depending on the compaction strategy defined on the table. Cheers!

Comment: The fact that the latest wins is clear, but how does it change the underlying structure and keeps it in well defined state ? (e.g. if insertions are placed into an event loop so there's only one actual insertion at a time it's fine but if we had `N ` threads doing insertions to the same  in memory structure that would theoretically result in a race condition.

Comment: Mutations are just appended so no race condition. When the data is flushed to disk, they get merged/sorted and any duplicates get resolved based on "latest timestamp wins". Cheers!